# Do you have to build your own satellite in sterile conditions?

Tags: artificial-satellite, contamination

If you were to build your own satellite (say, like a CubeSat), is it required to build it in sterile conditions? The satellite would never reach another planet/the Moon so I wouldn't have thought that contamination is an issue.

Answer (score 5):

No, sterile conditions aren't necessary for most spacecraft. Satellites are usually built in a cleanroom to prevent dust and dirt getting in and causing problems like electrical shorts, dirt in moving parts causing extra wear, and contamination of optical systems.